# VisualStudio 2013 debugging freezes entire system

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013

I have a weird problem with VS debugging which drives me crazy - in **SOME** projects putting breakpoints in **SOME** places causes my system work veeeery slow. The mouse moves with 1 second delay also as keyboard input. Stopping debugging removes this effect.
I can't describe for sure what causes it to work so slow. But a breakpoint in the begin of **main()** function works good. Other breakpoint deep down the call hierarchy freezes my machine.
I have VS2013 Update 4, Windows 7, C++ project. I tried to turn off every debugging option, removed different temp files, cleared project folder.
The same project on other machine works fine. Also, the same compiler/debugger, but with Qt creator works also fine (thought different project).

Comment: did you try, instead of disable debugging, simply removing all breakpoints and then putting them again? i had a similar issue with a suddenly very long startup

Comment: Maybe have a look at this thread https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/583539/debugger-needs-a-long-time-to-start-and-stop-removing-the-suo-file-fixes-the-problem

Comment: For me it starts ok. I tried to remove all breakpoints, tried to remove *.suo also.